# Executing a list of functions on an array

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm getting to grips with using functional programming beyond a simple `map` or two. I have a situation where I want to be able to filter some elements from an array of objects, based on a particular field of those objects. It's a contrived example, but here goes:

I have a list of field definitions, and I want to extract two of them based on their title.

```
const toSearch = [
  { title: "name", description: "Their name" },
  { title: "age", description: "Their age" },
  { title: "gender", description: "Their gender" }
]

const fieldsToFind = ["name", "age"]
let filterObjects = R.map(R.objOf('title'), fieldsToFind)
let filterFuncs = R.map(R.whereEq(R.__), filterObjects)
let found = R.map(R.filter, filterFuncs)

console.log("Filter objects:", JSON.stringify(filterObjects))
console.log("Filter functions:", JSON.stringify(filterFuncs))

console.log("Found:", found[0](toSearch))
console.log("Found:", found[1](toSearch))
```

If I run this, the last of the output is the two elements of `toSearch` that I'm looking for, but it's not exactly neat. I've been trying to get another `map` working to get around executing `found` elements manually, but I also feel that even leading up to that point I'm taking an overly circuitous route.

Although it's a contrived example, is there a neater way of accomplishing this in a functional style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One fairly simple way of doing this is:

```
R.filter(R.where({R.title: R.contains(R.__, ['name', 'age'])}))(toSearch);
//=> [
//     {"description": "Their name", "title": "name"}, 
//     {"description": "Their age", "title": "age"}
//   ]
```

or, equivalently,

```
R.filter(R.where({title: R.flip(R.contains)(['name', 'age'])}))(toSearch);
```

One advantage, especially if you import the relevant functions from `R` into your scope, is how closely this reads to your problem domain:

```
var myFunc = filter(where({title: contains(__, ['name', 'age'])}));
```

> myFunc = filter where the title contains 'name' or 'age'.

You can see this in action on the **[Ramda REPL](http://goo.gl/kNSBhA)**.

Comment: That last one is great! Just the kind of neatness I'm looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.reduce` to accomplish your task. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) has a very brief explanation of the reduce function

Comment: Can I use reduce if I want more than one element from the input array, though? I guess I could use an array as the accumulator.

Comment: You can use any type as acc. Just provide an empty array as initial value

Answer (score 0):

> I have a situation where I want to be able to filter some elements
>   from an array of objects, based on a particular field of those
>   objects.

For your situation, its quite simple

```
var filteredItems = toSearch.filter(function(value){ return fieldsToFind.indexOf(value.title) != -1 });
```

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely the sensible way to go. In a way I'm trying to find an overly complicated solution to this just to get some insight into chaining the functions together.